# Getting 'IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable' when using scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, numerical-methods

For the code below:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from math import *

N = 40
m = 4/N
D = (70/40)*N
g = 9.81
y1, z1 = -2, 1
yn, zn = 2, 1
y_l = linspace(y1, yn, num=N)
z_l = linspace(z1, zn, num=N)

x = stack((y_l, z_l))

def V_g(x):
    z_sum = 0
    for i in x[1]:
        z_sum += i
    return z_sum

def V_spring(x):
    sum_list = []
    y = x[0]
    z = x[1]
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        sum_list.append((y[i] - y[i+1])**2 + (z[i] - z[i+1])**2)
    vs = sum(sum_list)
    return vs

def V(x):
    return (0.5*D*V_spring(x)) + (m*g*V_g(x))

res = minimize(V, x)
print(res)
```

I receive the following error:

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable
```

For the line

```
        sum_list.append((y[i] - y[i+1])**2 + (z[i] - z[i+1])**2)
```

Can someone please help me out?

The task is to minimise the potential energy of a chain given by:

[This equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWafW.png)

[For this boundary condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3ptd.png)

Please note that in the potential energy equation there is a typo in the first part of the equation, it should read:

Sum(from i = 1, to N-1) [D* (y_i - y_i+1)^2...]

From the code above, I first created two 'initial guess' lists of 'y' and 'z' (which are horizontal and vertical coordinates, respectively), then created a stacked array. Using V_g (that is the second part of the potential energy equation) and V_spring (which is the first part), the summations are calculated and finally using V, the overall potential energy is calculated and then fed to 'res' which attempts to minimize this value/function and return a 'new' array with updated coordinates of each mass in the chain.